# Trying to plot a simple function - python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, machine-learning, linear-regression

I implemented a simple linear regression and I want to try it out by fitting a non linear model

specifically I am trying to fit a model for the function `y = x^3 + 5` for example

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def predict(X,W):
    return np.dot(X,W)

def gradient(X, Y, W, regTerm=0):
    return (-np.dot(X.T, Y) + np.dot(np.dot(X.T,X),W))/(m*k) + regTerm * W /(n*k)

def cost(X, Y, W, regTerm=0):
    m, k = Y.shape
    n, k = W.shape
    Yhat = predict(X, W)
    return np.trace(np.dot(Y-Yhat,(Y-Yhat).T))/(2*m*k) + regTerm * np.trace(np.dot(W,W.T)) / (2*n*k)

def Rsquared(X, Y, W):
    m, k = Y.shape
    SSres = cost(X, Y, W)
    Ybar = np.mean(Y,axis=0)
    Ybar = np.matlib.repmat(Ybar, m, 1)
    SStot = np.trace(np.dot(Y-Ybar,(Y-Ybar).T))

    return 1-SSres/SStot

m = 10
n = 200
k = 1

trX = np.random.rand(m, n)
trX[:, 0] = 1

for i in range(2, n):
    trX[:, i] = trX[:, 1] ** i

trY = trX[:, 1] ** 3 + 5
trY = np.reshape(trY, (m, k))

W = np.random.rand(n, k)

numIter = 10000
learningRate = 0.5

for i in range(0, numIter):
    W = W - learningRate * gradient(trX, trY, W)

domain = np.linspace(0,1,100000)
powerDomain = np.copy(domain)
m = powerDomain.shape[0]
powerDomain = np.reshape(powerDomain, (m, 1))
powerDomain = np.matlib.repmat(powerDomain, 1, n)

for i in range(1, n):
    powerDomain[:, i] = powerDomain[:, 0] ** i

print(Rsquared(trX, trY, W))
plt.plot(trX[:, 1],trY,'o', domain, predict(powerDomain, W),'r')
plt.show()
```

the R^2 I'm getting is very close to 1, meaning I found a very good fit to the training data, but it isn't shown on the plots. When I plot the data, it usually looks like this:

[image]

it looks as if I'm underfitting the data, but with such a complex hypothesis, with 200 features (meaning i allow polynomials up to x^200) and only 10 training examples, I should very clearly be overfitting data, so I expect the red line to pass through all the blue points and go wild between them.

This isn't what I'm getting which is confusing to me.
What's wrong?

Comment: First thing first, fix this: `trX = np.random.rand(m) ** np.arange(n)`

Comment: and `powerDomain = domain ** np.arange(n)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `powerDomain[:,0]=1`, that's why your plot goes wrong at `0`. And yes you are over fitting: look how quickly your plot fires up as soon as you get out of your training domain.